# Weird problem with address(this).balance and gas

Tags: gas, addresses, constructor

I have a very simple contract, something like this:

```
contract Test_Variable{

    uint256 public variable;

    constructor() {
        variable = 100;
    }

    function balanceTest() public {
        variable = address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

In Remix, I run the balanceTest function. It fails and reports "out of gas".
If I delete "variable = 100" from constructor, then balanceTest can run without problem.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem about JVM in Remix IDE. In fact, if you deploy your smart contract into Web3 with Environment dropdown in `Deploy & run transactions` section, you can see that your smart contract works!

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed a problem caused by JVM, I tried the Web3 approach and it works!